# Python run script when Tkinter button pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make it so that the variable `fpl` is set when the button (command submit) is used. The problem is, it runs through the entire thing before the user has hit the button. How do i make it so the script beginning?

```
#Convert string to list
fpl = fpl.replace(" " , ".")
```

Is only run once the user has pressed the button? Rest of the code below.

```
import json
from tkinter import *

def submit():
    fpl = entry.get()

window = Tk()
window.title ("Infinite FMS")

Label (window, text="Enter your flight plan 
here:").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)

entry = Entry(window, width = 75, bg = "light blue")
entry.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

Button (window, text="Submit", 
command=submit).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

output = Text(window,width=75,height=6,background="light 
blue")
output.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)

#Convert string to list
fpl = fpl.replace(" " , ".")

"[" + fpl + "]"

fpllist = fpl.split(".")
#Length of fpllist
fpllen = len(fpllist)

#Loop through the flight plan missing first and last 
entries
n = 1
Invalid = []
while n < fpllen - 1:
    #Check for item in file
    searchTerm = (fpllist[n])
    searchTermF = "\'Name\': \'" + searchTerm + "\'"
    searchTermV = "\'identifier\': \'" + searchTerm + "\'"
    file = open('mydirectory', 'r')
    data1 = json.load(file)
    file.close()
    file = open('mydirectory', 'r')
    data2 = json.load(file)
    file.close()
    if searchTermF in str(data1):
        Validity = "Your route is valid!"
        n = n + 1
    elif searchTermV in str(data2):
        Validity = "Your route is valid!"
        n = n + 1
    else:
         Validity = "Your route is invalid!\nInvalid 
waypoints:"
    Invalid.append(searchTerm)
    n = n + 1                    
if len(Invalid) == 0:
    print (Validity , ', '.join(Invalid))
else:
    Validity = "Your route is invalid!\nInvalid 
waypoints:"
    print (Validity , ', '.join(Invalid))

output.delete(0.0, END)
output.insert(END, (Validity , ', '.join(Invalid)))
```

Comment: I haven't examined your code closely, but why don't you put all that stuff from `fpl = fpl.replace(" " , ".")` onwards inside the the `submit` function?

Comment: Please can you review this and amend accordingly https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are trying to get `fpl` formatted as and what it is you want to do with `fpl` once its formatted. This info would help considerably. And please fix your indention in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PM 2Ring said if you put this

```
#Convert string to list
fpl = fpl.replace(" " , ".")

"[" + fpl + "]" #what is this supposed to do?

fpllist = fpl.split(".")
#Length of fpllist
fpllen = len(fpllist)
```

in your `submit` function it will be run when you click the button.
Also you don't need to replace the spaces with points `fpllist = fpl.split()` will give you the same result.

And you should really learn OOP(google it if you don't know what it is) it will make your program more readable and you can split diffrent parts of your program in diffrent functions.